# IP proto field number to string

Tags: python, scapy

Using scapy, how can I get a string with the name of an IP protocol from the number on the packet proto field?

For example, converting 6 to 'TCP'.

Comment: Please provide some code showing us your research and your effort to solve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scapy is awesome but the documentation leaves a lot to be desired. This works:

```
from scapy.all import *

def ip_proto(pkt):
    proto_field = pkt.get_field('proto')
    return proto_field.i2s[pkt.proto]

x = IP() / TCP()
print ip_proto(x)
```

Comment: Thank you.
Just for completion, you need an IP packet to use this method. For instance, if you have an Ethernet packet you need to get the IP packet first:

`ip_proto(eth_packet[IP])`

Comment: For more universal, when you get a  Ethernet packet, use `payload` to specify the next layer:   `ip_proto(eth_packet.payload)`, but you should first confirm the payload exists